# intellij java desktop application how to use resources

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am busy with a java desktop application in intellij. I am struggling to get a image to display in a JLabel

Here is my current code (in a class extending JPanel):

```
icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/icon.png"));
lblIcon.setIcon(icon);
```

Here is a picture of my project structure:

[image]

The image is in the resources directory and the screen in in the screens\jpanel.java directory

Comment: How about simply `getClass().getResource("icon.png")`?

Comment: Have you tried `.getResource("icon.png")` ?

Comment: `getClass().getResource("/icon.png")`

Comment: The `src/main/resources` directory is a "root", meaning resource names should be relative to that directory. Also check out the documentation of [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)); it explains the difference between absolute and relative resource names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I rememeber correctly, IntelliJ automatically adds the contents of the folder marked as "resources root" to the root of your compiled project.

`getClass().getResource("...")` expects a path relative to your classloader, thus you simply need to provide the name of your image in this case:

```java
icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icon.png"));
lblIcon.setIcon(icon);
```